# Permutation and Combinations (Separation)

Tags: permutations, combinations

Eight students are to be arranged in a row. Find the number of ways to arrange them if three particular students must be separated.

Comment: This means that three students have to stand next to each other?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Three student must be separated.However my teacher and fellow friend ask me to count the three as one.

Comment: In my opinion,I grouped 5 student and 3 particular students which must be separated.So, it become 5! x 3! x 18 = 12960.
The '18' is coming from the number of way i can arrange them by listing in a table. Is the answer correct ? However the answer given by teacher is 14400. my teacher also having a headache with this question. So please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:First we arrange five students excluding the three that should be separated. Then what we should do is put the rest of the 3 in the gaps of the five student. There are altogether 6 places to arrange these 3 (4 gaps and the 2 corners). So from the first part we have 5! and the second part for which 3 must be arranged can you make a guess?

Comment: I kinda confused. 5! x 3! ? or 6! x 3! ?
Please help me explain further.

Comment: It is 5!*$\binom{6}{3}*3!$

Comment: @user162096 When you arrange the 3 people between the gaps of the 5 people they will always remain separated.

Comment: I edited my comment.After choosing the 3 gaps and filling them they can be further arranged in 3! ways. So my 1st comment gives the final answer

Comment: Oh. I see. Sorry for my bad understanding and thank you from helping me.